# Print string backwards while removing characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

This prints the word while removing characters from the beginning.

```
word = "word"

length = len(word)
for s in range(0, length):
    print(word[s:])
    s=+1
```

So the output is

```
word
ord
rd
d
```

How do I flip it around so it would print the word backwards while removing characters?
So that the output would be:

```
drow
row
ow
w
```

Comment: FYI, `s=+1` assigns the value `+1` to `s`, and `s` is overwritten immediately anyway by the next loop iteration. In other words, it doesn't do what you think it does and is in fact superfluous.

Comment: See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python). Oh and the `s=+1` is not needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
for s in range(0, length):
    print(word[::-1][s:])
```

The `[::-1]` slice reverses the string. The downside to this is the double slices which both create a new `str` object.

Answer (score 3):

Simply (with single *reversed* slicing):

```
word = "word"
for i in range(0, len(word)):
    print(word[-1-i::-1])
```

- `-1-i` - negative starting index, to slice on reversed sequence

The output:

```
drow
row
ow
w
```